# Get IDs of invited Facebook users

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I am using Facebook C# SDK and want to do a counter which counts the IDs of Facebook users who are invited to a URL.

In application, for example a person invites his/her friends to the application but I want to know how many people did he or she sent that invitation and who they are. So I must take an array that contains the IDs of invited Facebook users, then split it, then I can easily count how many people were invited.

Is this possible? I mean, how can I get the IDs of invited users?

Comment: What do you mean by "invited to a URL"? Is this a group, page, event or something else?

Comment: it is an application people who enter that facebook application will show a video and invite button when they invite their friends i must count it and learn the invited people's ids.

Answer (score 0):

This is against the [Facebook Platform Policies](http://developers.facebook.com/policy/): see point IV 1: "You must not incentivize users to use (or gate content behind the use of) Facebook social channels". Point VII 2 states that invites are included under the definition of 'social channels'.

As such, I doubt that it is possible - and if it is, then it sounds like you'd be breaking these policies.

Comment: but in VII.2

2.By "Facebook social channel" we mean Application Info Section, Application tab, Feed, requests (including invites), inbox attachments, Chat, Bookmarks, or any other feature of a user profile or Facebook communication channel in which or through which an application can provide, display, or deliver content directed at, on behalf of, or by permission of a user.

i understand that it says it requires a permission right? so if i get the right permission from the user, i can do it legally. do i understand wrong or not?

Comment: It's not a case of getting permission - it's a rule that you must stick to.